# jQuery .html() not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

jQuery `.html()` not working in Internet Explorer.

But if I do `.text()` it is working.

I do need to render those as HTML. I am banging my head for the last couple of days. Any work around will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
    {   import { Assessment } from "../models/qti/assessment";
import { TestPart } from "../models/qti/test-part";
import { Section } from "../models/qti/section";
import { Item } from "../models/qti/item";
import { Text, Interaction, InteractionType, Options, OptionText } from "../models/qti/interactions";

declare var X2JS: any;
declare var $: any;

export class QTITransformer {
  private qp_raw: any;
  private _xml_to_Json: any;
  private qpDetails: any;


  constructor(private rawData: any) {
    this.qp_raw = rawData;
    this._xml_to_Json = new X2JS({});
    console.log('inside constructor');
    this.qpDetails = this._xml_to_Json.xml_str2json(this.qp_raw['jQTIXML']);
    console.log('inside constructor:',this.qpDetails);
  }

  public getAssessmentObject(): Assessment {
    let assessment = new Assessment();
    if (this.qpDetails.hasOwnProperty('assessmentTest')) {
      if (this.qpDetails['assessmentTest'].hasOwnProperty('_identifier')) assessment.identifier = this.qpDetails['assessmentTest']['_identifier'];
      if (this.qpDetails['assessmentTest'].hasOwnProperty('_title')) assessment.title = this.qpDetails['assessmentTest']['_title'];
      if (this.qpDetails['assessmentTest'].hasOwnProperty('testPart')) {
        assessment.test_parts = this.getTestPartObject();
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Invalid QP : QTITransformer(testPart)');
      }
    }
    else {
      throw new Error('Invalid QP : QTITransformer(assessmentTest)');
    }
    return assessment;
  }

  public getTestPartObject(): TestPart[] {
    let testPartDetails = this.qpDetails['assessmentTest']['testPart'];
    let testpart = new TestPart();
    let testparts = [];
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(testPartDetails) === '[object Array]') {


    }
    else {
      if (testPartDetails.hasOwnProperty('_identifier')) testpart.identifier = testPartDetails['_identifier'];
      if (testPartDetails.hasOwnProperty('_navigationMode')) testpart.navigationMode = testPartDetails['_navigationMode'];
      if (testPartDetails.hasOwnProperty('_submissionMode')) testpart.identifier = testPartDetails['_submissionMode'];
      if (testPartDetails.hasOwnProperty('_duration')) testpart.identifier = testPartDetails['_duration'];
      if (testPartDetails.hasOwnProperty('assessmentSection')) {
        testpart.sections = this.getAssessmentSectionObject(testPartDetails['assessmentSection']);
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Invalid QP : QTITransformer(assessmentSection)');
      }
      testparts.push(testpart);
    }
    return testparts;

  }

  public getAssessmentSectionObject(sectionDetailsRaw: any): Section[] {
    let section = new Section();
    let sections = [];
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(sectionDetailsRaw) === '[object Array]') {
      for (let sectionDetails of sectionDetailsRaw) {
        section = new Section();
        if (sectionDetails.hasOwnProperty('_identifier')) section.identifier = sectionDetails['_identifier'];
        if (sectionDetails.hasOwnProperty('_title')) section.title = sectionDetails['_title'];
        if (sectionDetails.hasOwnProperty('_visible')) section.visible = sectionDetails['_visible'];
        if (sectionDetails['ordering'].hasOwnProperty('_shuffle')) section.shuffle = sectionDetails['ordering']['_shuffle'];
        if (sectionDetails.hasOwnProperty('assessmentItemRef')) {
          section.items = this.getAssessmentItemObject(sectionDetails['assessmentItemRef']);
        }
        else {
          throw new Error('Invalid QP : QTITransformer(assessmentItemRef)');
        }
        sections.push(section);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (sectionDetailsRaw.hasOwnProperty('_identifier')) section.identifier = sectionDetailsRaw['_identifier'];
      if (sectionDetailsRaw.hasOwnProperty('_title')) section.title = sectionDetailsRaw['_title'];
      if (sectionDetailsRaw.hasOwnProperty('_visible')) section.visible = sectionDetailsRaw['_visible'];
      if (sectionDetailsRaw['ordering'].hasOwnProperty('_shuffle')) section.shuffle = sectionDetailsRaw['ordering']['_shuffle'];
      if (sectionDetailsRaw.hasOwnProperty('assessmentItemRef')) {
        section.items = this.getAssessmentItemObject(sectionDetailsRaw['assessmentItemRef']);
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Invalid QP : QTITransformer(assessmentItemRef)');
      }
      sections.push(section);
    }

    return sections;

  }
  public getItembyID(id: string): any {
    let itemRaw = this.qp_raw['testPaperMetadataDetails']['assetsContentInformation'];
    return itemRaw[id];
  }
  public getAssessmentItemObject(itemDetailsRaw: any): Item[] {
    let item = new Item();
    let itemRaw = "";
    let items = [];
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(itemDetailsRaw) === '[object Array]') {
      for (let itemXml of itemDetailsRaw) {
        item = new Item();

        itemRaw = this.getItembyID(itemXml['_identifier']);
        item.assertId = itemXml['_identifier'];
        let itemJsObj = $($.parseXML(itemRaw['jQTIXML']));
        let imgContent = itemRaw['resourcesInformation'];
        let rubricBlock = itemJsObj.find("*").filter(function () {
          return this.nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("rubricblock") >= 0;
        });
        let infoControl = itemJsObj.find("*").filter(function () {
          return this.nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("infocontrol") >= 0;
        });
        let blockquote = itemJsObj.find("*").filter(function () {
          return this.nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("blockquote") >= 0;
        });
        let content = new Text();
        content.lang = "default";
        if (blockquote.length > 0) {
          content.text = blockquote.text();
          item.itemBlockquote = [content];
        }
        if (infoControl.length > 0) {
          content = new Text();
          content.lang = "default";
          content.text = infoControl.text();
          item.itemInfoHint = [content];
        }
        if (rubricBlock.length > 0) {
          content = new Text();
          content.lang = "default";
          content.text = rubricBlock.text();
          item.itemRubrick = [content];
        }

        if ($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('identifier')) item.identifier = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('identifier');
        if ($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('title')) item.title = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('title');
        if ($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('label')) item.label = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('label');
        if ($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('lang')) item.lang = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('lang');
        if ($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('adaptive')) item.adaptive = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('adaptive');
        if ($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('timeDependent')) item.timeDependent = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('timeDependent');
        if ($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('toolName')) item.toolName = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('toolName');
        if ($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('toolVersion')) item.toolVersion = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').attr('toolVersion');
        let qMainBody = $(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').children('itembody').children('div').children('p').text();
        // console.log("Getting qmainbody:");
        if (qMainBody !== "") {
          let questiontextparse = $('<div/>').text($(itemJsObj).children('assessmentitem').children('itembody').children('div').children('p').text().replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&amp;/g, '&'));
          questiontextparse.find("img").each(function () {
            let imageName = $(this).attr('src').trim();
            if (imgContent[imageName] !== null) {
              $(this).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imgContent[imageName]['resourceContent']);
            }
            $(this).attr('src');
          });;
          item.qMainBody = questiontextparse.html();
          //item.qMainBody = qMainBody;

        }
        else {
          item.qMainBody = "";
        }
        item.interactions = this.getInteractionObject(itemRaw['jQTIXML'], imgContent);
        if (item.interactions.length > 1) {
          item.isMultipleInteraction = true;
        }
        else {
          item.isMultipleInteraction = false;
        }
        items.push(item);
      }
    }
    else {

    }
    return items;
  }

  public getInteractionObject(itemRawXml: any, imageContent: any): Interaction[] {
    let interaction = new Interaction();
    let interacitions = [];
    let itemJsonObj = this._xml_to_Json.xml_str2json(itemRawXml);
    let itemJsObj = $($.parseXML(itemRawXml));
    let interactionObjests = itemJsObj.find("*").filter(function () {
      return this.nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("interaction") >= 0;
    });
    let responseObjects = itemJsObj.find("*").filter(function () {
      return this.nodeName.indexOf("responseProcessing") >= 0;
    });
   // console.log("----------------");
   // console.log(responseObjects.text());
   // console.log(responseObjects.html());
   // console.log($(responseObjects));
   // console.log("----------------");


    for (var i = 0; i < interactionObjests.length; i++) {
      interaction = new Interaction();
      switch (interactionObjests[i].nodeName) {
        case InteractionType[InteractionType.choiceInteraction]:
          interaction = this.getchoiceInteractionObject(interactionObjests[i], imageContent, responseObjects);
          break;
        case InteractionType[InteractionType.extendedTextInteraction]:
          break;
        case InteractionType[InteractionType.inlineChoiceInteraction]:
          break;
        default: throw new Error('Not Supported Interaction Type : QTITransformer(getInteractionObject)' + interactionObjests[i].nodeName + InteractionType.choiceInteraction.toLocaleString());
      }
      interacitions.push(interaction);
    }
    //console.log(interactionObjests);
    return interacitions;
  }

  public getchoiceInteractionObject(interactionNode: any, imageContent: any, responseObjects: any): Interaction {
    let interaction = new Interaction();
    let interactionText = new Text();
    interaction.type = InteractionType.choiceInteraction;
    if ($(interactionNode).attr('id')) interaction.id = $(interactionNode).attr('id');
    if ($(interactionNode).attr('lang')) interaction.lang = $(interactionNode).attr('lang');
    if ($(interactionNode).attr('responseIdentifier')) interaction.responseIdentifier = $(interactionNode).attr('responseIdentifier');
    for (var i = 0; i < $(responseObjects).children('responseCondition').length; i++) {
      if($($(responseObjects).children('responseCondition')[i]).children('responseIf').children('match').children('correct').attr('identifier') == interaction.responseIdentifier)
      {
       interaction.score =  $($(responseObjects).children('responseCondition')[i]).children('responseIf').children('setOutcomeValue').children('baseValue').text();
      }
      //console.log("#########");
      //console.log($($(responseObjects).children('responseCondition')[i]).children('responseIf').children('match').children('correct').attr('identifier'));
      //console.log($(responseObjects).children('responseCondition')[i]);
      //console.log("#########");
    }

    if ($(interactionNode).attr('maxChoices')) interaction.maxChoices = $(interactionNode).attr('maxChoices');
    if ($(interactionNode).attr('shuffle')) interaction.shuffle = $(interactionNode).attr('shuffle');
    if ($(interactionNode).children('prompt')) {
      interactionText.lang = "default";
      let questiontextparse = $('<div/>').text($(interactionNode).children('prompt').text().replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&amp;/g, '&'));
      //console.log($(interactionNode).children('prompt').text());
      questiontextparse.find("img").each(function () {
        let imageName = $(this).attr('src').trim();
        if (imageContent[imageName] !== null) {
          $(this).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageContent[imageName]['resourceContent']);
        }
        $(this).attr('src');
      });;
      interactionText.text = questiontextparse.html();

      //interactionText.text = $('<div/>').html($(interactionNode).children('prompt').html()).text().replace('1.JPG','/assets/1.JPG');
      interaction.interactionText = [interactionText];
    }
    if ($(interactionNode).children('simplechoice')) {
      let optionsNodes = $(interactionNode).find("*").filter(function () {
        return this.nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("simplechoice") >= 0;
      });

      let optionsObj = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < optionsNodes.length; i++) {
        let optionObj = new Options();
        let optionTextObj = new OptionText();
        if ($(optionsNodes[i]).attr('id')) optionObj.id = $(optionsNodes[i]).attr('id');
        if ($(optionsNodes[i]).attr('lan')) optionObj.lang = $(optionsNodes[i]).attr('lan');
        if ($(optionsNodes[i]).attr('identifier')) optionObj.identifier = $(optionsNodes[i]).attr('identifier');
        optionTextObj.lang = "default";
        console.log($(optionsNodes[i]))
        let optiontextparse = $('<div/>').text($(optionsNodes[i]).text().replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&amp;/g, '&'));
        //console.log($(optionsNodes[i]).html());
        optiontextparse.find("img").each(function () {
          let imageName = $(this).attr('src').trim();
          if (imageContent[imageName] !== null) {
            $(this).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageContent[imageName]['resourceContent']);
          }
          $(this).attr('src');
        });;
        //optionTextObj.text = $(optionsNodes[i]).html().replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
        optionTextObj.text = optiontextparse.html();
        optionObj.OptionText = [optionTextObj];
        optionsObj.push(optionObj);
      }
      interaction.Options = optionsObj;
    }
    return interaction;
  }

  public htmlDecode(input) {
    var e = document.createElement('div');

    e.innerHTML = input;

    return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }


  public decodeHtmlEntity(str) {
    return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function (match, dec) {
      return String.fromCharCode(dec);
    });
  };


  public getExtendedTextInteraction(interactionNode: any): Interaction {
    let interaction = new Interaction();
    let interactionText = new Text();

    return interaction;
  }
}
    }
```

Comment: what mean by not working, any error? do you console.log it what is the value inside?

Comment: What is `itemJsObj` ?

Comment: Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and learn how to create REPRODUCIBLE issues in your questions before shouting out loud about a jQuery method not working.

Comment: This is exact file where we have written a util.service.ts which is basically getting the questions for database and parsing as xml and showing in while creating dynamic element. I am new to this project and doesn't know much about it. Has given only make it work in Internet Explorer. I am sorry for the partial details.

Comment: Below is the error , I am getting                                                             
           ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Comment: $('<div/>').html(), what is alternative of the 'div ' self closing tag ?

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer will only insert a HTML string using jQuery's .html() method if every tag is properly formatted. Other web browsers are less strict about a missing tag.